# Firefox backdrop-filter: blur() not working with Sticky positioning

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, google-chrome, firefox

I am using react with styled components and tailwind. For some reason, when using Firefox. The backdrop-filter: blur() will not work. This however is not an issue when using chrome. Not completely sure why this is happening. I remember reading that Firefox was weird with blur, but I don't understand why it will work, just not with sticky positioning, and the problem is only on Firefox. Suggestions gladly accepted

I added backdrop-filter: blur() to the container that I need to blur, I load it up in Google Chrome, its fine. When I goto load the page on Firefox, the blur does not exist. If I remove the sticky positioning from the element, the blur will work as expected on Firefox

Also, I made sure that the blur is enabled in my settings

Answer (score 2):

> Edit: I came across [this bug entry](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1803813) that summarizes and confirms my findings described here.

After setting up some test cases, I figured out what is causing the issue (at least in my case). Without seeing your code example (simplified), it's hard to tell if your setup is similar to mine, but here's what I found out (hoping it helps you and the folks out there).

Following setup is causing the backdrop-filter not to work in Firefox (tested in version 114 on macOS):

1. The element with the `backdrop-filter: blur();` has `position: sticky;` set
2. A parent element has a `border-radius` and `overflow` property set

[CodePen with the setup](https://codepen.io/glmvc/pen/bGQNqPP)

**Removing one or both of the mentioned properties of the parent element will make the backdrop-filter work in Firefox.**

I know that this is a very specific setup, but maybe your mentioned styled components or tailwind is creating this setup...

I tried to find a working solution, such as adding an inner container or a pseudo element to set the filter on, but nothing worked.